# since which version does linux kernel support multi touch screen?

Tags: linux, touch-screen

I'm having a Linux 2.6.37 kernel on hand and I'd like to know if it support multi-touch screen.
If so, I'd like to know since which version does Linux starts to support multi-touch and to what extend, also which multi-touch protocol does the kernel support.
I tried to find the information on the internet but cannot obtain a satisfying conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

From 2.6.30, acording this unofficial announcement: http://nuigroup.com/forums/viewthread/6029/, however it is not only kernel problem, it has very much to do with xorg interfaces. The problem in depth and modules needed are covered in Xorg and kernel module for multitouch researcher site: http://lii-enac.fr/en/architecture/linux-input/index.html#drivers .

These drivers are old and information might be outdated for a present day kernels and xorg versions. However from your question it looks like you are keen on using old kernel, so this might be for you.